# What is the use of sed in make file in below diagram?

Tags: shell, sed, makefile

I am following tutorial https://makefiletutorial.com/#pattern-rules

Recursive use of make

> To recursively call a makefile, use the special `$(MAKE)` instead of
> `make` because it will pass the make flags for you and won't itself
> be affected by them.
>
> ```
> new_contents = "hello:\n\ttouch inside_file"
> all:
>   mkdir -p subdir
>   printf $(new_contents) | sed -e 's/^ //' > subdir/makefile
>   cd subdir && $(MAKE)
>
> clean:
>   rm -rf subdir
> ```

I don't understand the line

```
    printf $(new_contents) | sed -e 's/^ //' > subdir/makefile
```

Can anyone tell whats `sed -e 's/^ //'` doing?

I tried to compile and got the make file generated in the subfolder.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Have you read the `sed` man page? What was unclear about the documentation?

Comment: It _is_ mysterious because nothing in `new_contents` contains a leading space. The code is basically doing nothing. My _guess_ is that the author tried to figure out how to print a leading tab, and somehow left in code which isn't doing anything from while they were figuring it out.

Comment: I found a duplicate which asks about a similar construct. The duplicate is somewhat more complex, but it covers all of the ground here, and then some.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be a little bit unspecific. What do you not understand?

In the following line:

```bash
printf $(new_contents) | sed -e 's/^ //' > subdir/makefile
```

- `printf $(new_contents)` writes the contents of the Make variable `new_contents` to `stdout`.
- `sed -e 's/^ //'` searches the content for any line beginning with a leading space and deletes this space. `s/^ //` is a regular expression. BTW the `-e` option is unnecessary in this case, but it's more explicit.
- `> subdir/makefile` writes the result to a file called *makefile* inside the subdirectory *subdir*

Thats it.

Comment: Correction: the `sed` step removes one leading space character from *every* line that has one.  Which does not appear to serve any useful purpose, as it doesn't look like any lines being output contain a leading space.

Comment: (I edited to correct that, but I guess the comment could still remain to point out how this is pointless.)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for the correction. Yes, it is pointless in the special case posted initally. But because the question is so unspecific about what the OP does not understand, I just posted a general answer ;)